# Why do Google SMTP server not work anymore?

Tags: smtp, phpmailer

I have used Google SMTP server for several years to send mail from my webpage but it does not work anymore. Nothing in my PHPMailer script is changed.

```
 $mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
 $mail->Port = 465;
 $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
```

I get the following error.

```
 SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

Is this something Google have changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has a long history of breaking SMTP authentication. Set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2` and read the SMTP transcript, which will give you some clues. then read [the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#gmail-oauth2-and-allow-less-secure-apps) which has lots to say on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

I allowed less secure apps in google secure settings and now it's working again.